# Calculation in TikZ coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could somebody tell me why with that code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\newcommand{\loga}[1]{{log10(#1)}}

%definition longueurs------
\def\lMarqueStd{0.4}
\def\vMin{1}
\def\homothRap{1}
%--------------------------


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\homothRap{1}
\draw (\lMarqueStd,-\homothRap*\loga\vMin)--++(-\lMarqueStd,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get an error? It sure comes frome `\homothRap*`. I try do fix it with some `$` but I failed.

Could somebody help me please?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to not use directly `(\lMarqueStd,{-\homothRap*log10(\vMin)})`?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino : juste laziness but you're right it works in that case

Comment: Put math operations in a brace pairwhen used as coordinate expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra pair of braces from the `\newcommand` definition and add them back in around the entire calculation in the coordinate expression:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\newcommand{\loga}[1]{log10(#1)} % removed brace pair here

%definition longueurs------
\def\lMarqueStd{0.4}
\def\vMin{1}
\def\homothRap{1}
%--------------------------


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\homothRap{1}
\draw (\lMarqueStd,{-\homothRap*\loga\vMin})--++(-\lMarqueStd,0); % added brace pair here
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The braces must encapsulate the entire calculation inside a coordinate expression, not just part of it.